# How to show only the parent page title if it has child pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a great question to the experts in wordpress.

```
I have created four pages. 
1. Home
2. About
3. HTML
4. CSS
```

From these page i have choosen a sub pages for HTML and CSS as

```
HTML - Parent Page
--Basic HTML -sub page for html
--Intermediate HTML - sub page for html

CSS - Parent Page
--Basic CSS - sub page for css
--Advance CSS - sub page for css.
```

Now my question is, I need code to display only the title of the parent pages. That is HTML and CSS. Not the sub pages.. And also the HOME and ABOUT page should not be displayed.

Simply say that, i need only the parent pages title if it has child pages..

Please anyone give me the code for this one..

Comment: it means are you only looking for those page names which have child pages..?

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using the [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) function.

The function offers many more arguments, but the one I think you need is `include` -

> **include** (string) Only include certain Pages in the list generated by wp_list_pages. Like exclude, this parameter takes a comma-separated list of Page IDs. There is no default value. See the Include Pages in List example below.

So assuming your ID's for the pages HTML and CSS are 6 and 8 (change as necessary), you'd use -

```
$args = array(
    'include' => '6,8'
);
wp_list_pages($args);
```

Comment: Ya its ok but in future i need to add some more parent pages. that is more than 20..

Answer (score 0):

try this one: it will display only those page's name which have child pages:

```
if( count( get_pages("child_of="$post->ID) ) != 0 ) { echo $post->post_title;} // Has Children
```

Thanks

Comment: if i simply add this code, it shows me the error like this "unexpected T_VARIABLE"..

Comment: after including global $post before the mentioned code also it was showing the same error..

Comment: can you please share your page code here....and i would also want to clarify that you are only want those page names which have child pages, right..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41465/discussion-between-krunal-shah-and-user2644743)